# java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()

Tags: java, android

I have two file with name

- FirstFragment.java
- SecondFragment.java

**Code of the FirstFragment is**

```
package com.example.application

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);


        return view;
    }

    // The method that i want to call from SecondFragment
    public void methodFirst() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Method First Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

---

Now I want to call the *methodFirst* function in SecondFragment. I have tried the following code on SecondFragment.

**Code of the SecondFragment is**

```
package com.example.application

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    Private AppCompatButton btnOneSecondFragment;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

        btnOneSecondFragment = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_one_second_fragment);

        FirstFragment firstFrag = new FirstFragment();

        btnOneSecondFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                firstFrag.methodFirst();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
}
```

But the following error is displaying

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
> object reference

Comment: Either you're passing a null in for a Context somewhere, or you're not posting the relevant code.  Where is the code in SecondFragment being called, is it possible its called before the context is set up for the fragment (if this is in a constructor or init block, that's wrong).

Comment: `FirstFragment firstFrag = new FirstFragment();` You are not supposed to use the 'new' operator to create fragments.

Comment: @gabe-sechan
 Hi I have updated the code please give some suggestion on my code, thank

Comment: Yeah, no context is ever set on that fragment, as its never attached to a view anywhere.  So getContext() in it returns null.  You need to actually put it into your layout.

Comment: @blackapps Using new to create a fragment isn't that unusual.  You sometimes don't want to or can't put the fragment into your xml.  In that case, creating it with new is normal, and then you'd add it into your screen via a FragmentTransaction.  Of course until you do so it doesn't have a Context and shouldn't be accessed.